# How can I animate SVG text to be "written out"

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to animate an svg as if it's being written out, like [this example on Codepen.](https://codepen.io/tigercodes/pen/bGWmQRV)

I'm trying to understand how to do this by comparing svg elements but so far I'm not seeing much difference. I replaced the svg in the codepen with my own but it wouldn't work. Why is this? And how could I make my own SVG's (such as the one below) animate in the same fashion as on the Codepen? (Besides replacing the path id!)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="417.773" height="224.047" viewBox="0 0 417.773 224.047">
  <path id="Path_35" data-name="Path 35" d="M-3.875-234.323c-1.516,0-8.928,23.415-22.236,70.078-2.021.842-29.143,6.907-81.533,18.193-.505,0-.842-.674-1.348-2.021.842-1.179,6.57-22.742,16.846-64.687,0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-1.179,0-7.581,22.91-18.867,68.73q-8.844,3.285-95.01,23.584c-35.881,7.917-53.906,12.3-53.906,13.477v2.021a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,2.021.674q56.1-14.15,143.525-33.691c0,.505.168.674.674.674h.674q0,1.516-23.584,92.988a4.017,4.017,0,0,1,.674,2.021h2.7l25.605-96.357c10.276-3.538,37.566-9.6,81.533-18.193h.674q-17.435,69.236-33.691,141.5c.674,1.853,1.348,2.7,2.021,2.7h.674l1.348-.674c11.624-53.738,23.415-101.916,35.039-144.873,38.408-8.591,66.035-12.8,82.881-12.8h5.391l3.369,3.369h.674c.674,0,1.348-.842,2.021-2.7,0-3.2-3.2-4.717-9.434-4.717h-.674c-15.5,0-42.451,3.875-80.859,11.455,0-.505-.505-.674-1.348-.674,2.7-11.624,9.265-33.86,19.541-66.709,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm14.993,93.662c-8.254,0-13.982,6.738-17.519,20.215,0,6.57,4.548,10.276,13.477,11.455,9.434,0,19.036-7.917,28.975-23.584,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021H33.354c-8.76,13.477-16.677,20.215-23.584,20.215H2.358a7.891,7.891,0,0,1-4.043-4.043v-2.021a26.887,26.887,0,0,1,1.348-6.064c11.624-3.706,17.519-6.57,17.519-8.76v-2.021a5.721,5.721,0,0,0-5.391-3.369Zm-8.591,9.939c1.516-3.2,3.369-4.885,5.559-5.222l3.369-.168-4.717,2.864ZM98.716-238.029c-1.516,0-3.875,6.738-7.412,20.215q-4.3,20.973-34.365,78.838c-8.254,14.319-13.645,21.562-16.172,21.562H38.745c-1.853-.505-2.7-2.527-2.7-6.064v-10.107c14.487-43.63,24.089-76.311,28.975-97.7-.337-3.2-1.011-4.717-2.021-4.717H60.981l-4.043,4.043c-17.014,44.978-25.605,79.006-25.605,101.748v4.043c0,7.581,2.527,12.129,7.412,13.477,7.581,0,20.215-18.025,37.734-53.906h.674c-3.538,17.183-5.391,29.817-5.391,37.734v4.043c0,6.233,1.516,10.276,4.717,12.129h2.7c4.548,0,11.624-7.244,21.562-21.562-.505,0-.674-.505-.674-1.348H98.042C88.1-123.479,81.533-117.414,78.5-117.414c-1.348-.337-2.021-2.19-2.021-5.391v-4.717c0-12.971,3.2-31.838,9.434-56.6,10.276-31,15.5-48.347,15.5-51.885,0-1.348-.505-2.021-1.348-2.021Zm-41.1,17.519v.674c-2.19,11.118-6.738,26.448-13.477,45.82h-.674v-.674c0-5.054,4.548-20.383,13.477-45.82ZM106.3-139.482c-6.57,0-11.118,6.738-13.477,20.215,0,6.233,2.864,9.939,8.76,11.455,4.548,0,8.928-4.043,13.477-12.129,14.319-5.391,22.4-9.939,24.258-13.477v-.674c0-.842-.505-1.179-1.348-1.348h-1.348c-8.591,5.9-14.656,8.76-18.193,8.76h-.674C116.909-135.271,113.035-139.482,106.3-139.482Zm-1.348,5.391c3.875-1.516,6.57.168,8.086,5.391v2.021q-6.822,0-8.086-6.064Zm-4.717,5.391c4.885,3.706,8.423,5.9,10.781,6.738-2.021,5.9-4.885,8.76-8.76,8.76h-2.021c-1.348-.674-2.19-2.358-2.7-5.222C97.2-121.12,98.042-124.49,100.232-128.7Zm51.211,7.244c-4.043,0-7.075,2.19-8.928,6.738l3.032,2.864c5.728-1.685,8.928-3.538,9.6-5.728-.168-2.527-.842-3.875-1.685-3.875Z" transform="translate(262.624 238.029)" fill="#949ba5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your SVG is a filled path; you need a stroke. See MDN: [Fills and Strokes](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes).

Comment: Ahhh thank you! That makes a lot more sense. Would you also be able to tell me how I'd set a beginning and end to the animation? I used stroke and got it to animate but it's now filling all over the place.

Comment: 1. you need a continous path like *ello* but unlike the *H* in your example. 2. You need to know the path length. You will use this as a value for stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset. In order to know the path length you may use javascript and the `getTotalLength()` method

Comment: You can also add a pathLength attribute to the path and set it =100 - which avoids having to use getTotalLength and makes it a lot easier to reason about things like % completion.

Comment: Alternative using a native Web Component ``<draw-path>`` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975967/how-to-animate-shape-or-image-file-along-svg-paths-with-the-vivus-js/66064211#66064211

Comment: Thank you all for your advice and input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And how could I make my own SVG's (such as the one below) animate in
> the same fashion as on the Codepen? (Besides replacing the path id!)

For this you need to change your SVG

Your shapes is drawn with double paths:

[image]

You need to redraw the shape using single paths and make the line thicker (`stroke-width ="6"`)

[image]

This is how it looks in the end:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8">
<g fill="none" stroke="#949BA5" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="horizont"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"/> 
  
<path id="vert1" d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" />
<path id="vert2" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6" />
<path id="sign" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" />
<path id="dot" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Animating one element with `stroke-dashoffset`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8" style="background:#151515">
<g fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="0s;anSign.end+1s"
    dur="3s"
    values="750;0"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</svg>
```

Animating all the elements of the shape:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8" style="background:#151515">
<g fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="Horizont" stroke-dashoffset="337" stroke-dasharray="337"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"> 
   <animate id="anHorizont" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert1.end+0.25s" dur="0.3s" values="337;0" fill="freeze"/>
</path> 
                   <!-- Length = 173px -->
<path id="Vert1" stroke-dashoffset="173" stroke-dasharray="173"  d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" >
    <animate id="anVert1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert2.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="173;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
                   <!-- Length = 232px -->
<path id="Vert2" stroke-dashoffset="232" stroke-dasharray="232" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6"> 
     <animate id="anVert2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="232;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
   
     <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" values="750;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
    
<path id="Dot" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" >
      <animate id="anDot"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.2s" dur="0.25s" values="25;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</g>
</svg>
```

Color scheme option as in the question:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 417.8 224" height="224" width="417.8">
<g fill="none" stroke="#949BA5" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
   <!-- Length = 337px -->
<path id="Horizont" stroke-dashoffset="337" stroke-dasharray="337"  d="M3.8 130l82.4-20 60.3-13.8L213.7 81l56.2-11 25-4.2s21.7-3 32.5-2c3.3.3 5 3 5 3"> 
   <animate id="anHorizont" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert1.end+0.25s" dur="0.3s" values="337;0" fill="freeze"/>
</path> 
                   <!-- Length = 173px -->
<path id="Vert1" stroke-dashoffset="173" stroke-dasharray="173"  d="M169.1 24l-15 55.5-10.5 41.6-17.8 70" >
    <animate id="anVert1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anVert2.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="173;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
                   <!-- Length = 232px -->
<path id="Vert2" stroke-dashoffset="232" stroke-dasharray="232" d="M259.3 5.8l-7.8 23.7L241 63.2l-8.6 33.2L220 148l-11.5 49.8-5.3 22.6"> 
     <animate id="anVert2"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.25s" dur="0.25s" values="232;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
   
      <!-- Length = 750px -->
<path id="Sign" stroke-dashoffset="750" stroke-dasharray="750" d="M259.8 110.4s6-1.4 10.3-3.4c2.8-1.3 6.8-2 6.8-4.9 0-1.5-2-2.6-3.5-2.7-3.4-.4-7 1.6-9.3 4.1-3.6 4-5.7 10.2-5 15.6.4 2.5 2 5 4.3 6.2 3.2 1.7 7.4 1.3 11 .4 5-1.4 9.7-4.3 13.3-8.1 5.8-6.2 8.5-14.8 11.7-22.6 2.7-6.8 4-14 6.3-20.9 2.2-6.8 7.2-20.4 7.2-20.4l7.3-25s2.8-8.8 3.6-13.4c.7-3.6 4.6-9.9 1-11-3.4-1.2-4 6-5.5 9.3-3 6.1-7 19.3-7 19.3l-5.7 17.4-5.2 22.2-4.4 19a54.5 54.5 0 00-1.4 20.6c.5 3.6 2.3 9.7 3.8 10.3 2 .7 4.2 1 6.2-.7 3.4-3 6.3-6.5 9-10.2 4.5-6.4 8-13.5 11.7-20.3 3-5.3 6-10.7 8.7-16l7.6-15.1L354 32.5s4-13.3 6.2-20c1.9-6.8 4.2-13 1.3-11-3.3 6.2-4.9 15.6-6.9 22.1-2.1 7-11.3 41.8-11.3 41.8l-4.2 22.3-2.2 19.8s-.7 7.2.2 10.7c.5 1.9 1 4.6 3 5.1 3 .9 6.1-2.4 8.3-4.4 2.5-2.3 7-7.2 7-7.2s3.6-5 6.5-6.8c3.3-2-2.8 6.3-3.4 9.7-.5 3-1.5 6.5 0 9.1 1.2 2.2 3.9 4.1 6.4 4 3.5 0 6.5-3.1 8.7-5.8 2.4-3 4.2-6.7 4.5-10.5.2-2.2-.2-4.7-1.6-6.4-1.8-2.3-4.9-4.2-7.8-4-2.6.2-6.2 2-6.4 4.5-.2 2.4 3.2 3.7 5.1 5 2.3 1.6 5 3 7.7 3.3 3 .5 6.2-.2 9.2-1a42 42 0 0015.8-8.6" >
    <animate id="anSign" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="2s" values="750;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
    
<path id="Dot" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M407 123c0-2 2.7-3.6 4-4.2 1.6-.8 2.2-.7 4-1 1 0 1.4 2 1 3-.2.7-2.9 1.7-1.8 1.3 0 0-4 2.6-5.9 2.4-.7 0-1.4-.8-1.4-1.5z" >
      <animate id="anDot"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="anSign.end+0.2s" dur="0.25s" values="25;0" fill="freeze" />
</path>   
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This definitely helps a lot, I really appreciate your tutorial! May I ask, what program are you using to redraw the path?

Comment: @KaiI am using Inkscape