# svg handwriting effect ,Can I clip the stroke path to a png image instead of text?

Tags: css, animation, svg, svg-animate, handwriting

first of all, Im new to this webpage and Im really sorry for any mistakes.

So, I needed to animate a **png image** of a **Calligraphy text** just like a **handwriting effect**.
Recently I've watched a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wab7lQKHXL4, its about making a handwriting animation with strokes clipped to texts.
So I was wondering, if I could clip the strokes to a *png image* and animate it just like the handwriting animation.

I tried to import the png image inside inkspace and drawn path on top of it, gave suitable stroke-width saved it as a svg file, and tried to animate it with stroke-dasharray, but its not working ,its not even showing up.
although I can do the same with written texts just like in the video.

So is there any way ,I can achieve the same goal using a png image.
thanks in advance, and sorry if I don't make any sense

Comment: Could you explain more what effect you want to achieve? How does the 'unveiling' of the png occur? With text there is a known order in which things need to be revealed - it follows handwriting - but there is no such direction indication on a png. I feel the best you could do is something like slowly reveal it either left to right or top to bottom or diagonally.

Comment: Please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-handwriting-animation-with-irregular-svg-strokes/

Comment: Using your PNG as **background**, you have to draw the path as shown in the video yourself. After that use that path in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975967/how-to-animate-shape-or-image-file-along-svg-paths-with-the-vivus-js/66064211#66064211) doing all the JavaScript and stroke-dasharray magic for you.

Comment: A Haworth
Sorry , I couldnt find any reply button or anything. So there is this video.<"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tlp4Gm--c4"> , this is what I wanted.The video shows animating a text, an svg image and a png image using strokes. but unfortunately this is done on Adobe xd. is there any way that i can do it with inkspace and css?

Comment: @enxaneta
 already checked that article. thats also about animating text(fonts) . but I can i use the same masking and effects with a png .its actually a png image of a logo, i wanted to apply the handwriting effect to that png.

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman thanks, but Ive tried using png as background and drawn paths and clipped the paths to png, and tried to animate it with stroke-dasharray, but its not showing up. there is this video "youtube.com/watch?v=_tlp4Gm--c4" which animates a text, a svg image and a png image with strokes. Can i do the same with inkspace and some css?

Answer (score 0):

The video you are linking is astonishing, if not crooked. The commentary points out it is done with a "custom" version of Inkscape, and I have to say there are some UI elements I have never seen. (Admittedly, I am on an older version from 2021, but the video is from 2017, when Inkscape oficially wasn't even on verson 1.0.) Maybe the specialists on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ can tell you more about this "custom" version?

The core action is selecting from the menu bar *Object -> Set Clip*. If this is the same as selecting *Object -> Clip -> Set* in my version (1.02), **this cannot work**. This action sets a [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path). Clip paths only clip to their *fill* area and **have no stroke properties**.

What you have to do instead is

1. set the fill to `none` and the stroke color to white (`#ffffff`)
2. select a *Object -> Mask -> Set*

Also, even after watching for multiple times, I am not sure on which element the `onload` attribute is set. Setting it on the path element in the mask certainly won't work, there is no `load` event happening there.

The logical choice would be to wait for the *image* loading.

The result should be something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('image#letter').addEventListener('load', function () {
  setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#stroke .dashed').style.strokeDashoffset = 0, 200)
})
```

```css
.dashed {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
}
image#letter {
    mask: url(#stroke);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <mask id="stroke" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <path class="dashed" d="M 61.739,30.223 C 61.739,30.223 55.369,26.515 51.839,25.606 48.819,24.825 45.469,24.022 42.489,24.964 40.379,25.63 38.329,27.161 37.349,29.137 35.899,32.044 35.099,36.236 36.989,38.878 36.989,38.878 46.459,41.753 50.839,42.679 54.399,43.431 57.729,48.053 56.429,52.972 55.599,56.117 51.469,57.478 48.379,58.502 45.569,59.433 42.389,59.495 39.509,58.837 36.089,58.056 30.199,53.913 30.199,53.913" />
  </mask>
  <image id="letter" width="100" height="100"
         xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAACXBIWXMAAA7DAAAOwwHHb6hkAAAA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"
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `d-path`, you can offload the work to a Native Web Component `<draw-path>`

**disclaimer**: The ***last*** drawn path is from Jake Archibald his 2013 blog: [Animated Line Drawing SVG](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/)

```js
window.customElements.define("draw-path", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let template = (id) => document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true);
      super() // super sets and returns this scope
        .attachShadow({mode: "open"}) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot
        .append(template(this.nodeName));
      this.line = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#line");
      this.line.setAttribute("d", this.getAttribute("d") || "m10 60c30-70 55-70 75 0s55 70 85 0");
      this.line.setAttribute("stroke", this.getAttribute("stroke") || "black");
      this.line.setAttribute("stroke-width", this.getAttribute("stroke-width") || "2");
      this.pen = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#pen");
      this.onmouseover = (evt) => this.draw();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("viewBox",this.getAttribute("viewBox")||"0 0 180 150");
      this.draw();
    }
    showpen(state = true, scale) {
      this.pen.style.display = state ? 'initial' : 'none';
    }
    draw() {
      clearInterval(this.drawing);
      this.showpen();
      this.dashoffset = 1;
      this.pathlength = this.line.getTotalLength();
      this.drawing = setInterval(() => this.update(), 50);
    }
    update() {
      this.dashoffset -= this.getAttribute("speed") || 0.02;
      let {x,y} = this.line.getPointAtLength(this.pathlength - this.dashoffset * this.pathlength);
      this.pen.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${x-2} ${y-2})`);
      this.line.style.strokeDashoffset = this.dashoffset;
      if (this.dashoffset <= 0) this.end();
    }
    end() {
      clearInterval(this.drawing);
      this.showpen(false);
      //console.log("end",this.line);
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = setTimeout(()=>this.draw(),2000);
    }
  });
```

```html
<draw-path viewBox="20 20 60 60" d='M 61.739,30.223 C 61.739,30.223 55.369,26.515 51.839,25.606 48.819,24.825 45.469,24.022 42.489,24.964 40.379,25.63 38.329,27.161 37.349,29.137 35.899,32.044 35.099,36.236 36.989,38.878 36.989,38.878 46.459,41.753 50.839,42.679 54.399,43.431 57.729,48.053 56.429,52.972 55.599,56.117 51.469,57.478 48.379,58.502 45.569,59.433 42.389,59.495 39.509,58.837 36.089,58.056 30.199,53.913 30.199,53.913'></draw-path>
<draw-path stroke='red' stroke-width='8' speed=".01"></draw-path>
<draw-path stroke="deeppink" viewBox="0 0 400 370" d="M11.6 269s-19.7-42.4 6.06-68.2 48.5-6.06 59.1 12.1l-3.03 28.8 209-227s45.5-21.2 60.6 1.52c15.2 22.7-3.03 47-3.03 47l-225 229s33.1-12 48.5 7.58c50 63.6-50 97-62.1 37.9"></draw-path>

<template id="DRAW-PATH">
  <style>
    :host {  display: inline-block }
    svg { width: 180px; height: 130px; background: beige }
  </style>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id='line' pathlength='1' stroke-dasharray='1' stroke-dashoffse='1' fill='transparent'/>
    <path id='pen' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' fill='gold' d='m12 19l7-7l3 3l-7 7l-3-3zm6-6l-2-8l-14-3l4 15l7 1l5-5zm-16-11l8 8m-1 1a2 2 0 104 0a2 2 0 10-4 0'/>
  </svg>
</template>
```

**Note:**

Be aware `M` or `m` (moves) in paths create a **new** *stroke*,  drawn at the same time, not sequentially.

So `stroke-dash*` settings are applied concurrent.

That is why in all blogs you only see **single stroke** simple paths or polylines used.